# Android JUnit testing not firing test methods

Tags: android, junit, android-testing

I don't know if I'm really rusty with JUnit or their is a concept with Android Testing in particular I'm not familiar with but:

I'm finding it very difficult to understand how my tests get run.

I've created a Test Project based on my main project, and created a class which extends `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<SinglePaneActivity>` and in this Test Case I've implemented `setUp()`, `testPort()` and `tearDown()` methods.

When I run the project as a Android JUnit test it all tests correctly.

However, adding another class extending `ServiceTestCase<NativeService>` with the same `setUp()`, `testStart()` and `tearDown()` methods implemented, the test isn't performed.

Looking through the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html) I can't find anything which states *how* the tests are run, I'm assuming since their is no specific setup it done via reflection.

Given that as the case however, I don't understand the documentation on TestSuites or why my Service test case isn't running.

Am I the only one that's finding the usually very well written Android Documentation lacking when it comes to testing?

Comment: it is strange. Are you sure the process is not crashing and your are not get informed? Take a look to the logcat and see if it does contain more information about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Blackbelt says, the was a warning in the Log's indicating that the Test wasn't running.

My problem was that I had used the constructor auto generated for me by eclipse

```
public NativeServiceTestCase(Class<NativeService> activityClass) {
```

And the error was output as a warning in LogCat explaining you need to have an empty argument constructor (But that error wasn't repeated anywhere else with any visibility).